# Obtain first date in column after reference date

Tags: google-sheets, date-comparison

In cell B1, I have `=today()` for today's date and then in the cells below (B2:B100), What I'm trying to do is to compare the date in cell B1 (today's date) and to find the next date that appear in cells B2:B100 AFTER this date and then copy this into A2.

So, in effect, in cell A2, I want a function to look up the next date in cells B2:B100 that is the nearest one AFTER B1 and then copy this into A2. I know this is a formula to add in A2 but just unsure what formula to use.

I've tried this in cell A2,

```
=MIN(IF(B2:B100>B1, B2:B100))
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a valid problem description. Surely there was some sort of feedback you obtained from trying that and other formulas. Perhaps you got the wrong value, or an error. Those would be valid problem descriptions.

Comment: Consider learning about `FILTER`.

Comment: Also look at MINIFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Other things being equal", the formula is correct but should be entered in the array version (eg with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=ArrayFormula(MIN(IF(B2:B100>today(),B2:B100)))
```

Building the function from B1 into the formula is optional.